# automatic download for ubuntu mate is not starting

Tags: downloads, mate

by using direct link to download ubuntu mate 64 bit 19.10 the download is not starting automatically there is no other link to do so. Any suggestion to this problem??

Comment: That is most likely related to your browser, browser-extensions, or setup. It doesn't for me, but I'd not want it to (my browser setup won't run any scripts & has lots of features disabled by choice, I copy the link and `wget` the file from a different box)

Comment: Try disabling any adblocker, or just `wget` it: `wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/19.10/release/ubuntu-mate-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso`.